# Python/Javascript: WYSIWYG html editor - Handle large documents fast and/or design theory

Tags: python, html, wysiwyg

Background:

I am writing an ebook editing program in python. Currently it utilizes a source-code view for editing, and I would like to port it over to a wysiwyg view for editing. The best (only?) html renderer I could find for python was webkit (I am using the PyQt version).

Question:

How do I accomplish wysiwyg editing? The requirements/issues are as follows:

1. An ebook may be up to 10,000 paragraphs / 1,000,000
   characters.

   - PyQt Webkit (ContentEditable): No problem.
   - PyQt Webkit (TinyMce, etc): Takes *forever* to open them!
2. The format is `<body><p>...</p><p>...</p>...</body>`. The body element contains *only* paragraphs, there are no divs, etc (but in the paragraph there may be spans, links, etc.). Editing must take place with no significant delays as far as the user is concerned.

   - PyQt Webkit (ContentEditable): If you try deleting text across multiple paragraphs, it takes forever!! My understanding is that this is because it resets the common-parent of the elements being changed - i.e. **the entire body element**, since two different paragraphs are being deleted/merged. But, there should be no need for this - it should need only delete/merge/change those individual paragraphs!

I am open to implementing my own wysiwyg editing, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to delete/cut/paste/merge/change the html code correctly. I searched online for articles about html wysiwyg design theory, and came up dry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can i suggest a complete another approach ? Since your ebook is only `<p></p>`:

- Split the text on `<p></p>` to get an indexed array of all your paragraphs
- Make your own pagination system, and fill the screen with N paragraphs, that automatically get enough text to show from the indexed array
- When you are doing selection, you can use [paragraph index + character index in the paragraph] for selection start / end
- Then implement cut/copy/paste/delete/undo/redo based on thoses assumptions.

(Note: when you'll do a selection, since the start point is saved, you can safely change the text on the screen / pagination, until the selection end.)

Comment: Apologies. I meant that in `<body>` there are only `<p>`, but in `<p>` there may be `<span>`, `<a>`, `<sub>`, etc. So its not just a simple paragraph + character index. Also, it sounds interesting, but how would I go about with 'my own pagination system'? I need #1 an html renderer and #2 the ablity to scroll and select text on more than one 'page'. Then #3 to communicate the caret position + html changes with the renderer...

Comment: Yes, so you can write a little javascript for that. Whatever is the content inside `<p>`, you can still use that approach. And yes, you would need to do your own textinput (for selection etc), and update the html output according to `<p></p>`. (What i meant is `<p>` can be your "minimum item" to work with)